# Missing package class in eclipse after recovery

Tags: java, eclipse

I had a machine a Windows update corrupted and I had to copy my `eclipse-workspace` folder off to another machine.  I installed a slightly newer version (still in the 2022 year) of Eclipse on the new machine but it cannot find my source files.  They are there, but it is missing the `com.test` when it's looking for the file.

It's saying it cannot find `OBSTally/src/obstally` when the original path in the older version is `OBSTally/src/com/test/obstally`.

I'm sure I can't find/google the setting I need to change because I don't know it's proper name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your problem is but I'm guessing it has something to with eclipse not seeing folders or files or something.

First of all. Make sure the directory actually **exist** in the file explorer.

**Then right click your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path.**
Then select the **"source"** tab and press **"Add Folder"**

If the file is not there, then the other option **"Link Source"** might do it for you.

If that doesn't work then what I would do would be to remove the project from eclipse (don't delete the files) and then import the project again.

**Import > Existing Projects into Workspace**

If these two options don't work then the last option I know of is to simply create a separate project and then manually move all the files into the right spots.

Comment: Deleting the copied folder and performing an import fixed it *shrug*.  Somehow it lost the correct package name.  Now just have the mylyn issue to fix. Thanks